# How to accept only numeric input (double) in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want my Textinput to accept only float input directly from python code.
Here is what I have attempted:

```
TextInput(hint_text='Kgs', input_filter = float, multiline=False, write_tab=False)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
 TypeError: float expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

The following works in kv files:

```
TextInput:
  id: password
  input_filter: 'int' #For accepting ints
```

What is the correct way of doing in python file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the argument is a string so I think you should try this.

```
TextInput(hint_text='Kgs', input_filter = 'float', multiline=False, write_tab=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In .kv file, we act like this:

```
TextInput:
        id:cal_input
        text:"0"
        halign: "right"
        font_size:65
        size_hint:(1,0.15)
        hint_text:'Only Numbers'
        input_filter : 'float'
        multiline:False
        write_tab:False
```